# Is it possible to design a DFA for these languages?

Tags: regular-language, finite-state-machine

$$\mathcal{L}_1 = \{1^{\cdot n}w\mid,n\geq1, w \text{ has }n\text{ or more 1's}\}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_2 = \{1^{\cdot n}w\mid,n\geq1,w \text{ has }n\text{ or fewer 1's}\}$$

I am thinking that there shouldn't be a way for the DFA to know when to stop treating the string as $1^{\cdot n}$ and a way to remember the number of 1's seen.

I know that '111111' is both an accepted and unaccepted string depending on what $w$ we select, so for this purpose, we assume that a string is rejected only if there is no $w$ we can choose to accept it.

I got
$$\mathcal{L}_1 = 1\cdot\Sigma^*\cdot1\cdot\Sigma^*$$

but I am unsure about $$\mathcal{L}_2$$

Comment: I'm sightly confused, but I think I have an answer: I'll write it as one once I know I understand correctly. I'll demonstrate with $\mathcal{L}_1$ -- is $n$ fixed in advance, or is it variable? If it's fixed in advance, then just read the correct number of 1s, then count 1s in the remainder. If it isn't, shouldn't every string be accepted? Taking n=0 asks for nothing, followed by a string with at at least 0 ones.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Use the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) to show that these languages are not [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Comment: Do you know the myhill-nerode theorem? That's the quickest answer imo, but I'll point you towards a different solution if you don't know it

Comment: I think $\mathcal L_1$ *is* regular. Does it not consist of all binary strings that have $1$ as the first character and contain a total of at least two $1$s? That's what you've written (later) as well, and that's regular.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, $\mathcal L_1 = 1 \{0,1\}^* 1 \{0,1\}^*$, so it is [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

To show that $\mathcal L_2$ is not regular, we can use the pumping lemma.

> The [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) states that if $\mathcal L$ is a regular language, then there exists an integer $p \ge 1$ such that any word of $\mathcal L$ can be decomposed in the form $xyz$ with $|xy| \le p$ and $|y| \ge 1$, in such a way that $xy^nz$ is also a word of $\mathcal L$ for every $n \ge 0$.

Since the [reverse of a regular language is also regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties), we can restate the pumping lemma as (or obtain a corollary stating that) for any regular language $\mathcal L$, there exists an integer $q \ge 1$ such that every word of $\mathcal L$ can be decomposed in the form $uvw$ with $|vw| \le p$ and $|v| \ge 1$, in such a way that $uv^nw$ is also a word of $\mathcal L$ for each $n \ge 0$.

Now, suppose that $\mathcal L_2$ is regular. Then there exists $q \ge 1$ satisfying the condition stated above. Now consider the string $s = 1^q0^q$, which is a word of $\mathcal L_2$. Decomposing $s$ as $s = uvw$ in accordance with the restated pumping lemma, we see that $v = 1^r$ for some $r \ge 1$ (since $|vw| \le q$ and $|v| \ge 1$). But then, $uv^nw = 1^q0(1^{nr})1^{q - r} = 1^q01^{(n - 1)r + q}$ is also in $\mathcal L_2$. We can choose $n$ large enough so that $(n - 1)r + q > q$, resulting in a word that cannot be in $\mathcal L_2$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $\mathcal L_2$ is not regular.